# IIS6 + PHP upload

Tags: php, iis-6, configuration, upload

I have a problem with gettnig attache/upload to work on our support system.

We're running a IIS6+PHP5+MySQL setup for Kayako's SupportSuite, and everything is running just fine, except the upload/attachment function. When trying to attach a file to a ticket-reply the browser just "thinks" for a while then display an "cannot display the webpage" type of error page. My guess is that the request times out, without anything being uploaded.

I have no experience with running PHP on IIS before, so I might have missed some vital configuration when setting it up.

Does anyone have a off-the-top-of-my-head idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions.

The IIS worker process that runs the PHP interpreter needs write access to the folder where it's going to save uploaded files.

Comment: IIS_WPG and Internet Guest Account have write permission on the folder. Is there any other process/user that need access? Shouldn't I get a "forbidden" error code if the process wasn't permitted to write?

Comment: Which identity is the application pool configured to run as? If it's using the default, then it's NETWORK SERVICE; you should grant write access to that.

Comment: "Forbidden" is returned when the **client** can't do something; but in this case the client is simply requesting the execution of a script, it's the script itself that gets an error from the underlying O.S.; the most common result would be a 500 error, unless there's proper exception handling in the script.

Comment: You might be on to something with the application pool and NETWORK SERVICES. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct, but I ended up getting so tired of it that I switched to Apache instead...